# page break inside not working in my print

Tags: html, css, print-style

I have multiple components which looks like this:

```css
@media print {
  .print-wrapper {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="print-wrapper">
 <div data-appear-animation="fadeInRightBig" class="card animated fadeInRightBig mb-5 benchmarkCard">        <div role="tab" id="heading6" class="card-header">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#remarketingUtilization" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="remarketingUtilization" class="collapsed">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-refresh"></i> 
           <strong class="adwords-category">Remarketing Utilization</strong> 
            <span class="pull-right total-score">
                14%
            </span>
        </a>
    </div> 
    <div id="remarketingUtilization" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree" class="collapse show">
        <div class="card-block p-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    There are just 3 ways you can grow your business. By generating more Traffic,increasing
                    your Conversion Rate and optimizing Customer Value. But getting traffic
                    is easy... what will set you apart from the rest is building sustainable customer
                    relationships. Trust, relevance and user experience are the main ingredients
                    to achieve exactly that. Dasbot will assist you on all 3 growth levers. For instance, when
                    the Page Speed of your landing pages is slow, Dasbot will help you
                    optimize page load time.
    
                    <div class="btn-wrapper">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline mt-4 btn-compare">See
                            how you compare
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in my print.scss I say that card `page-break-inside` has to be avoiden:

```
 .card {
   page-break-inside: avoid;
 }
```

But this results in this output in print:

[image]

Comment: You don't have a page break in a div of class `card`. You have it between a div of class `card` and a div of class `card-block`.

Comment: wrap both `divs` in a `card` class and then it should do the trick

Comment: @Edwin I did wrapped the two divs but the same result

Comment: do you use it in the right `@media` (print) ?

Comment: yes everything else is working except for that

Comment: @Edwin really don't know what is going on here

Comment: add `display: inline-block;` to your card, can you maybe edit your post and use the html/css engine in place

Comment: @Edwin done and also tried `display: inline-block` but no result..

Comment: it's hard to tell exactly what is wrong, but I would play with the `width | min-width | height | min-height` css and see if something's changed.